# Anchor scrolling jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I found [this example](http://www.sycha.com/jquery-smooth-scrolling-internal-anchor-links). The code is quite old though, but it seems to do what I'm looking for:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".scroll").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
  });
});
```

And secondly, is it possible to make all anchors between a div called "navigation" to have this functionality, instead of adding a "scroll" class to every anchor?

Example:

```
<div id="section1">Scroll to me :P</div>
```

Comment: Can I see one of the element to which you want to scroll down to?

Comment: Technically, that would just be any element such as a <div>, <section> with an ID. So, in my case it's for example (edited above)

Comment: The code works with jQuery 1.8.2 - [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqgyh/). The HTML requires the anchor with class `scroll` to link to an anchor matching the ID of an element to which you want to scroll to.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you are right. I must have missed something out in my overloaded html file :P (I'll see if I can figure that part out), how about the other functionality (second) question, is that possible?

Comment: Can you try replacing "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {" with "jQuery(document).ready(function(event) {"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question, sounds like you want to attach the click handler to all children of a chosen element. Do it using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#navigation").on("click", "a", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
});
```

Where `"#navigation"` is the selector of the parent element you want, and `"a"` is a selector for the children.

Comment: Works like a charm, but I've realized it doesn't go to the top "all the way, have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/huJ95/ as you can see (i need to scroll a bit to see the text)

Comment: The page is scrolling so that the specified element is at the very top. Your `nav` is set to a fixed position, so it hides whatever is at the very top. The easiest thing to do would be to subtract the height of your `nav` from the `scrollTop` argument.